# Supporting both AutoLayout and traditional layout

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, autolayout, autoresizingmask

I have a custom subclass of UIButton that I want to re-use in multiple projects, some of which use interface builder and storyboards, and some of which may not.  It involves setting the button's frame in several places.

If I add

```
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

in the initialization, everything looks and works right, however, I get:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint…etc
```

logged to the console.  However, if I set

```
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

none of the button sizing works and the button is completely broken.

**Is there a way I can suppress the error since it seems to degrade to the right thing or can I somehow manually remove the offending constraint?**

I've tried dumping the constrains after the button is initialized, however, it does not seem to contain the constraint AutoLayout ends up breaking.

Edited: Below are links to a sample project and then my button code.  It works great when auto layout is turned off in the storyboard, however, when auto layout is turned on, the buttons seem to position at the origin (seems to be because when initWithCoder is called, the buttons don't have superviews or any position information).

http://www.kudit.com/dump/KFB.zip

http://www.kudit.com/dump/KuditConfirmButton.zip

Comment: I haven't found a way to do this other than manually setting the `translates...` property depending on the type of layout in use. How are you adding your button - as part of the xib/storyboard or in code?

Comment: As part of the storyboard.  I wanted to design the class so that I could just replace the class in IB and do the customizations using IB and runtime attributes to make a simple reusable drop-in solution.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show some of your code? Particularly any code where you create constraints. I'm assuming you're creating constraints internally to the button? You can put an autolayout view inside a non-autolayout view and vice versa, but you do get problems if you try to constrain an autoresized view. As it stands it's not clear from your question which you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Added sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct, in that when the buttons are initialized from the storyboard (using initWithCoder:) the frame is zero - this is expected for views using autolayout - frames don't get assigned until later on.

I have your sample project mostly working under autolayout by creating a boolean ivar called hasSetup, which get set to YES inside the setup method. The setup method doesn't run if the frame is zero. I also call it again from `layoutSubviews`. This gets around the not-working-when-using-autolayout in storyboard problem.

The various layers still aren't the correct size though. You may want to look into resizing them from layoutSubviews.

You also can't use `setFrame` under autolayout - you need to make sure any constraints on your view (like the sizing constraints from the storyboard) are adjusted instead. It's going to get quite messy dealing with both possibilities.

They look really good though - hope to see them on GitHub when you've sorted these problems.

Comment: So is there a way to detect auto layout?  Would querying .constraints work?  Also, there seems to be issues when being added programmatically vs. IB.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Adding programmatically, you'd have to set manually depending on the layout you were using. From a storyboard/xib, it would seem to make sense (though I haven't tested this) that the flag would be set appropriately based on the Autolayout status of the storyboard.

Comment: Can you point out where this "flag" is accessible via code? I didn't see any sort of "usesAutolayout" flag on either `UIStoryboard` or `UIView`.

Comment: I mean the translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints property on a UIView

Comment: The documentation says that flag is set by default and not necessarily indicative of whether the view it's in is using Autolayout or not :-/